# What can cause form API to ignore the weight of an element that is a collection of buttons?

Tags: 6, forms

I have two form elements on a node form I'm trying to order unsuccessfully. One is a standard collection of form buttons (submit, delete, etc) and another is a fieldset add by CCK. I am trying to order the submit button (one of the buttons in the collection) above the fieldset. I've set the #weight on the button collection (the parent form element of the submit) to a number lower than the #weight of the fieldset.

I've verified that after the #pre_render calls in drupal_render() the weight values I set earlier in my hook_form_alter persist. So nothing has changed them up to this point. I can confirm that changing the weight on the fieldset does it move it around, so I am having some impact on positioning.

Why does FAPI ignore the weights and still position the submit button at the bottom of the form? Or is there another point after drupal_render() that allows other modules to change form element weights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered this is expected behavior. The solution is to copy the buttons into new form elements, position them where desired, and remove the default buttons. Here are [step by step instructions](http://drupal.org/node/1415334) on how to do this.